# knockoutjs custom elements(components) , viewmodel properties undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

im stuck a bit with knockoutjs.
Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trajce/jyku8szf/) for the problem.
I've added some simplified logic there.
Shortly, i have a product list, i should populate it from server,
and on click on the product item i need the product data(with the observables), so i can update the other view models.
Note that not all properties are observables (names of products etc, wont change). Each product item is a ko component with viewmodel.

Why on button click, the properties of the **non-observables**, are **undefined**?
And also, check the **productTemplate**, im accessing some properties via *product*, and the observables via *$data* (they dont work otherwise - why?).
Thanks.

Here is sample html markup

```
<div class="products_wrapper">
    <section class="products">
        <ul data-bind="foreach: { data: products, as: 'product' }">
            <li>
                <product-item params="product: product"></product-item>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</div>
```

Here is the component code:

```
<script type="text/html" id='productTemplate'>
<button type="button" name="product" data-bind="attr: { id: product.ProductId }">
    <span data-bind='text: product.Name'></span>
    <span class="product-item-quantity" data-bind='text: $data.Quantity'></span>
</button></script>
```

and here are view models and component registration:

```
var some = some || {};
some.viewmodel = some.viewmodel || {};
some.viewmodel.product = function (item) {
  var self = this;
  //parameters
  self.ProductId = item.ProductId;
  self.Name = item.Name;
  self.Quantity = ko.observable(0);

  self.increaseQty = function increaseQty() {
    self.Quantity(self.Quantity() + 1);
  };
};

some.viewmodel.products = function () {
  var self = this;

  self.products = ko.observableArray();
  self.populate = function (data) {
    self.products(data);
  };
  self.getData = function () {
    self.populate(the json data here);
  };
};
ko.components.register('product-item', {
  viewModel: some.viewmodel.product,
  template: {
    element: 'productTemplate'
  }
});
```

Init here:

```
var products = new some.viewmodel.products();
ko.applyBindings(products, $('.products_wrapper')[0]);
products.getData();

$(".products").on('click', 'button', function () {
  var productcontext = ko.contextFor(this);
  var product = ko.dataFor(this);
  product.increaseQty();
  //$('.debug').append();//debug here
});
```

Comment: In your fiddle, `some` is not defined.

Comment: i've just updated the fiddle. sorry.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you need to insert `product` property like this:

```
  self.ProductId = item.product.ProductId;
  self.Name = item.product.Name;
```

Click a button at: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/jyku8szf/3/)